# linux kernel panic unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at

Tags: linux, kernel, panic, distcc

I'm facing issues with some kernel panic but I don't have any idea how to find which soft is exacly causing this issue. I'm trying to compile some soft on remote host using distcc software but my machines which are compiling are going down because of this issue.

Could you point me where shoud I start looking? What could cause this issue? Which tools should I use?

Here is kernel panic output:

```
[591792.656853] IP: [<          (null)>]           (null)
[591792.658710] PGD 800000032ca05067 PUD 327bc6067 PMD 0 
[591792.660439] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP 
[591792.661562] Modules linked in: fuse nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 dns_resolver nfs lockd grace fscache nls_utf8 isofs sunrpc dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod sb_edac iosf_mbi kvm_intel ppdev kvm irqbypass crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd cirrus ttm joydev drm_kms_helper sg virtio_balloon syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm parport_pc parport drm_panel_orientation_quirks pcspkr i2c_piix4 ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom virtio_blk virtio_net ata_generic pata_acpi crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32c_intel serio_raw floppy ata_piix libata virtio_pci virtio_ring virtio
[591792.682098] CPU: 2 PID: 25548 Comm: cc1plus Not tainted 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1
[591792.684495] Hardware name: Red Hat OpenStack Compute, BIOS 1.11.0-2.el7 04/01/2014
[591792.686923] task: ffff8ebb65ea1040 ti: ffff8ebb6b250000 task.ti: ffff8ebb6b250000
[591792.689315] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<          (null)>]           (null)
[591792.691729] RSP: 0018:ffff8ebb6b253da0  EFLAGS: 00010246
[591792.693438] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8ebb6b253e40 RCX: ffff8ebb6b253fd8
[591792.695716] RDX: ffff8ebb38098840 RSI: ffff8ebb6b253e40 RDI: ffff8ebb38098840
[591792.697992] RBP: ffff8ebb6b253e30 R08: 0000000000000100 R09: 0000000000000001
[591792.700271] R10: ffff8ebb7fd1f080 R11: ffffd7da0beb9380 R12: ffff8eb8417af000
[591792.702547] R13: ffff8eb875d1b000 R14: ffff8ebb6b253f24 R15: 0000000000000000
[591792.704821] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8ebb7fd00000(0063) knlGS:00000000f7524740
[591792.707397] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
[591792.709242] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000032eb0a000 CR4: 00000000003607e0
[591792.711519] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[591792.713814] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[591792.716100] Call Trace:
[591792.716927]  [<ffffffff9165270b>] ? path_openat+0x3eb/0x640
[591792.718727]  [<ffffffff91653dfd>] do_filp_open+0x4d/0xb0
[591792.720451]  [<ffffffff91661504>] ? __alloc_fd+0xc4/0x170
[591792.722267]  [<ffffffff9163ff27>] do_sys_open+0x137/0x240
[591792.724017]  [<ffffffff916a1fab>] compat_SyS_open+0x1b/0x20
[591792.725820]  [<ffffffff91b78bb0>] sysenter_dispatch+0xd/0x2b
[591792.727648] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[591792.728795] RIP  [<          (null)>]           (null)
[591792.730486]  RSP <ffff8ebb6b253da0>
[591792.731625] CR2: 0000000000000000
[591792.734935] ---[ end trace ccfdca9d4733e7a5 ]---
[591792.736450] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[591792.738708] Kernel Offset: 0x10400000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
```

Comment: Report that problem to the issue tracker for your distro vendor. Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker for other software.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to tell what went wrong with this just piece of log you have pasted.

It seems like oops lead into kernel panic!.

Well,with helping you to find the real cause,I can help you with material to look into for further dissection of panic/crash.

link 1: [analysing kernel panics](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html#mozTocId782257)

link 2 : [oops](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Oops,_Linux_crashes)

Hope it helps you! :)